# Symfony 2 : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 489 near 'r2_.job LIKE': Error: 'r2_' is not defined

Tags: doctrine-orm, alias, symfony-2.1

I am facing issue while calling child class property using alias which is generated automatically.

Here is query part that I have printed using getSQL() function. I can see that alias already generated in query.

```
SELECT r0_.id AS id0, r0_.title AS title1, r0_.created_at AS created_at5, r0_.updated_at AS updated_at6, r1_.date AS date7, r1_.job AS job8, r2_.date AS date13, r2_.time AS time14, r2_.job AS job15
FROM reports r0_ 
LEFT JOIN reports_small_works r1_ ON r0_.id = r1_.id 
LEFT JOIN reports_call_out r2_ ON r0_.id = r2_.id 
WHERE r0_.division_id = 1
ORDER BY r0_.id 
DESC
```

How can I use that reports_call_out alias? Reports is Parent Class and Reports_Call_out & Reports_small_works both are child class and append as LeftJoin default in Query.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that reports_call_out does not have "job" column, and you are trying to select it. Can you post your DQL using getDQL() function? To use joined table alias pass it after join like so:

```
SELECT ...
FROM reports r //r is alias for reports here
LEFT JOIN r.reports_call_out rco ...//rco is alias for reports_call_out here
```

Or if you are using [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) pass it like so:

```
/* ReportsRepository.php */
$this->createQueryBuilder('r')//r is alias for reports here
->select('...')
->leftJoin('r.reports_call_out', 'rco')//rco is alias for reports_call_out here
```

Comment: Yes i already did that but not added in query and report _call_out is by default assigned in query as left join because it's child of report class